# Should I check if an object exists in a collection before removing it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, collections

Say I have an object `someObject` and an `NSMutableArray *someArray`. I'm not sure if `someObject` is in the array, but if it is, I want to remove it. There are two options:

**Case 1:**

```
if([someArray indexOfObject:someObject] != NSNotFound)
   [someArray removeObject:someObject];
```

**Case 2:**

```
[someArray removeObject:someObject];
```

In case 2, if the object doesn't exist in the array, nothing happens. My question is, is case 2 more efficient, since in case 1 I'd have to search the array and see if it exists, and if it does, I remove it, but I'm guessing `removeObject:` searches the array again for that object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but I'm guessing removeObject: searches the array again for that object?

Well, yes, it has to. There's no way to find an object in a collection without looking for it.* [The docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBB) even say this:

> This method uses `indexOfObject:` to locate matches and then removes them by using `removeObjectAtIndex:`. [...] If the array does not contain `anObject`, the method has no effect (although it does incur the overhead of searching the contents).

You can of course imitate the framework and use `removeObjectAtIndex:` yourself right after the search if you want.

---

<sub>*This is faster than it might be (at worst O(log(N)) rather than O(N)) because `NSArray`s [aren't arrays](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html).</sub>

Comment: That link is really interesting

Comment: I'll amplify this slightly by saying: don't go out of your way to optimize NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString. They're fast, so do what's clean. Complicated optimization is likely not worth it, and might even be slower.

Answer (score 5):

Well, your array isn't going to remember every object you searched for.  If for some reason you need to know whether it was there before you removed it, you can avoid the double search with

```
NSUInteger tempIndex = [someArray indexOfObject:someObject];
if (tempIndex != NSNotFound)
   [someArray removeObjectAtIndex:tempIndex]
else
   //in case it wasn't found...
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NSMutableArray` does not (and cannot) "remember" that you just searched for an object when asked to remove it. Therefore, calling `indexOfObject` followed by `removeObject` necessarily takes more work than simply calling `removeObject` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with case 2 and just call removeObject because as the documentation states

> This method uses indexOfObject: to locate matches and then removes
>   them by using removeObjectAtIndex:. Thus, matches are determined on
>   the basis of an object’s response to the isEqual: message. If the
>   array does not contain anObject, the method has no effect (although it
>   does incur the overhead of searching the contents).

so basically the 2 code examples are identical, except that the array may do another check again after yours because it doesn't know you checked for that so its just some extra wasted cpu time. But in all honesty I wouldn't think too much about examples like this right now, and just develop your app and when it comes to optimization then look at whats taking up all your cpu time and adjust cases like this as they begin to really take up your cpu time.